# Can't store influxdata on persistent drive on a GCP computeengine using docker swarm (Not Kubernetes or InfluxDB Enterprise)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, debian, docker-swarm, influxdb

I'm running the TICK stack on a GCP compute engine through docker swarm but I'm having trouble storing the InfluxDB data on a seperate location so that when the VM reboots or the docker swarm is shut down the data won't dissapear.

In my Tick.yaml file for the services I'm using the following code for the influxDB:

```
influxdb:
image: influxdb
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.role == manager
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
volumes:
  # Mount for influxdb data directory
  - influxdb-data:/storage/influxdb
ports:
  # The API for InfluxDB is served on port 8086
  - "8086:8086"
```

I've checked documentation, configured the config file and a bunch of other things but can't get it to work. Would appreciate some assistance if anyone has an idea on where the problem might be.